# MATLAB: Calculate an average per every 5 minutes in serial-time

Tags: matlab, matrix, time, time-series

Using MATLAB (R2015b) I have a time-series `A` that is a 4000x3 matrix. Below is a sample where the first column is serial-time (here its from 13:56:37 to 14:25:09) and the second and third columns are measurements:

```
1.0e+05 *

7.366965809837962   0.000082000000000   0.062000000000000
7.366965810300925   0.000082500000000   0.013000000000000
7.366965836689815   0.000083000000000   0.040000000000000
7.366965857291667   0.000085000000000   0.013000000000000
7.366965875810186   0.000086000000000   0.010000000000000
7.366965876851851   0.000086000000000   0.020000000000000
7.366965889351852   0.000087000000000   0.015000000000000
7.366965892245370   0.000087000000000   0.016000000000000
7.366965896875000   0.000087000000000   0.004000000000000
7.366965897337963   0.000087500000000   0.050000000000000
7.366965901967592   0.000087500000000   0.002000000000000
7.366965906018518   0.000093000000000   0.010000000000000
7.366965907060185   0.000093000000000   0.010000000000000
7.366965928587963   0.000092000000000   0.010000000000000
7.366965962268518   0.000091500000000   0.030000000000000
7.366965973263889   0.000092000000000   0.001000000000000
7.366965974768519   0.000092000000000   0.050000000000000
7.366965982060186   0.000090000000000   0.010000000000000
7.366965993402777   0.000090000000000   0.090000000000000
7.366966007986111   0.000090000000000   0.043330000000000
```

How can I calculate the average for column two and three per every five minutes (instead of per event)? So for the first 5 minutes 13:55:00 - 14:00:00 we should get the average value 8.225 for middle column and 3750 for the right column, i.e. something like:

```
13:55:00  8.225  3750
14:00:00  8.4    2650
```

I have tried without success so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could help you

```
%Inital reference position
pos=1;

%Counter
count=1;

for i=2:20
    %Elapsed seconds since the reference position
    elapsed_seconds=etime(datevec(a(i,1)),datevec(a(pos,1)));
    if elapsed_seconds>5*60 %Calculate means if larger than 5 minutes
        matrix(count,1)=a(pos,1);
        matrix(count,2)=mean(a(pos:(i-1),2));
        matrix(count,3)=mean(a(pos:(i-1),3));
        count=count+1; %Update counter
        pos=i; %Update reference position
    end
end

matrix
```

Comment: I made some changes :)

Comment: I'm not sure this works completely. The elapsed time is calculated from `a(i,1)` to `a(pos,1)` but `a(pos,1)` does not necessarily start at the beginning of a 5 minute window.

Comment: The `pos` starts at 1 and is updated only when the `elapsed_seconds` is larger than 5*60 (after 5 minutes have passed). I think it works as it is :)

Comment: Consider if a(1,:) had the elements `[1.3,2,3,5.5,7,8,10.1]` measured in minutes. For the first 5 elapsed minutes, we take the average of the 1.3, 2, and 3 elements correctly. The algorithm then notices that 5.5 is outside the first elapsed 5 minutes and updates `pos` to it's index (index 4). We then start over again calculating elapsed time referenced to time 5.5 minutes. We then get elements 5.5, 7, 8, **AND** 10.1 in our second 5 minute window (10.1 is included because 10.1-5.5<5). This is wrong because 10.1 should have been in the _third_ 5 minute window.

Answer (score 1):

The nice thing about this problem is that you can break it into easy chunks. First of all, lets break the matrix in to vectors

```
times=A(1,:);
measurementX=A(2,:);
measurementY=A(3,:);
```

The second part is you need to break the time up into 5 minute increments. Lets make a vector of times starting at `7.366965809837962e5` (your first time) and going up to `7.366966007986111e5` (your last time) in 5 minute increments. Unfortunately, I cannot tell how many ticks exist in a 5 minute increment in MATLAB, I'll arbitrarily pretend it is 123e3. You will need to replace that number correctly.

```
timeIncrements=7.366965809837962e5:123e3:7.366966007986111e5
```

Now we need to find all indicies of times after the start of one increment and before the start of the next increment:

```
for (i=1:length(timeIncrements)-1)
    indicies{i}=times>timeIncrements(i)&&times<=timeIncrements(i+1);
end
```

Now we get the averages

```
for i=1:length(indicies)
    measurementX_5minIncrements(i)=mean(measurementX(indicies{i}));
    measurementY_5minIncrements(i)=mean(measurementY(indicies{i}));
end
```

**Huge Note!** This is untested but provides the general gist of what you need to do. I don't have access to MATLAB and can't play around to make sure it is correct. **Also,** this is *very* verbose, there is a two line answer to your problem but without actually using MATLAB I can't think it up (there was a time when I would have known it off the top of my head, but alas, that day is no more). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help! But could you please clarify what "timeBins" is (in the first for-loop)?

Comment: Bleh. My mistake. `timeBins` ==> `timeIncrements`.